# Rename file on Publish with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core service worker application, and have a need to rename the `appSettings.{environment}.config` file when publishing (not the build task).

How can I do this? I am doing this during the build, but this does not seem to apply during the publish.

Yes, this is so I do not have to deal with the environment variable at runtime. For reasons specific to our entire application suite, deploying and targeting a specific environment config is a huge complication at this time.

My goal is to just deploy the environment-specific config during publish, renamed to the non-specific `appSettings.config name`.

I do understand there is a difference between `CopyToOutputDirectory` and `CopyToPublishDirectory` in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: we have same problem, and instead of renaming (that created even more mess in the pipeline) we created `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` to match `environment` value in the appsettings.environment.json file name